# How to create a custom slot type?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I am trying to create a slot type to recognize a flight number for example 'VB001', 'VB002', 'VB101', 'VB201' it can be a random number with the 'VB' at the beginning.

I try adding a listo of slot values but it didn't work so I do no know how to create this custom slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a detailed tutorial on how you can create custom slots :
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html

However, you can skip the whole custom slot creation thing with a minor change in your sample utterances. As you said, your flight number is always going to have VB in the flight number. So you can create sample utterances like this: "`my flight number is VB {flightNumber}`" or "`my flight number is V B {flightNumber}`", and this `flightNumber` will have slot type of `Amazon.FOUR_DIGIT_NUMBER`.

Comment: Great solution! Tks